# Using 2^n steps to get every possible combination of people in a room

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, backtracking

Here is the excise:

> You start with an empty room and a group of n people waiting outside. At each step, you may either admit one person into the room, or let one out. Can you arrange a sequence of 2<sup>*n*</sup> steps, so that every possible combination of people is achieved exactly once?

---

My solution is:

I can have a bit array which has *n* elements. Each element's status stands for whether this person is in the room or not. So totally we will have 2<sup>*n*</sup> different combinations of people in the room.

The algorithm can be a standard backtrack to list out all the combinations.

---

I am just wondering whether my thought is too naive or simple?

Any trap in this excise?

---

**Edit:**

For people who are interested in the implementation of `gray code`, please see

http://yagni.com/graycode/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *The algorithm can be a standard backtrack to list out all the combinations.*

Your solution "works", but if implemented naively, it will requires a lot more than 2<sup>*n*</sup> steps.

See the following sentence in the problem statement:

> At each step, you may either admit one person into the room, or let one out.

In your solution, when you list all bit-vectors, you'll probably have `0111` followed by `1000` which means that three people will have to leave the room, and one person will have to enter.

That requires 4 steps, and not one, thus you'll get a lot more than 2<sup>*n*</sup> steps to run through all combinations.

However, you **can** arrange the bit-vectors you describe, in a way such that only **one bit differs** between two consecutive vectors. This is what is refered to as [*Gray code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Here's an example from the Wikipedia article:

```
Dec  Gray   Binary
 0   000    000
 1   001    001
 2   011    010
 3   010    011
 4   110    100
 5   111    101
 6   101    110
 7   100    111
```

Notice how

1. all bit-vectors are covered, and
2. for each consecutive vector, only one bit changes.

This means that you'll be able to iterate through all combinations in precisely 2<sup>*n*</sup> steps.

How to implement such sequence generator is also explained in the Wikipedia page, but if it's an exercise, I suggest you make an attempt yourself before peeking ;)

Comment: Thanks. You pointed out the "trap" I overlooked - the 2^n steps to get the result (not only to get 2^n combinations)

Comment: In particular, the straightforward method would involve about twice as many, approximately 2^(n+1), steps.

Comment: @ninjagecko it is 2^(n+1)-1 steps in my algorithm, just to be precise.

Comment: @aioobe, I have had a rough read for grey-code, but still can't understand it. for example, what is the rule for mapping the tray code  to the binary, as in your example.

Comment: I don't think there is a straight forward function to find the *k*:th bit vector. I think it's easiest to generate the whole sequence at once, as described in the wikipedia article.

Comment: So you mean I just generate gray code, and image the gray code sequence as my desired bit sequence (combinations). So in this way, we don't need to care about the actually binary vector (the right hand side of your example) because the gray code sequences are already a full set of combinations we desire.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution to the problem statement.

Comment: "I don't think there is a straight forward function to find the k:th bit vector." Depends on what you consider straightforward. You can find `G(k)` in O(log2(k)) time by a bit of bit-twiddling (also the inverse, find the index of a Gray code).

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a [*Gray code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) sequence generator.  Neighbouring values in a Gray code sequence differ by only one bit.

Comment: @JacksonTale: I don't know.  How are you ensuring that neighbouring values in your output sequence differ by only one bit?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code for gray code sequence generation

```
// Binary Reflected Gray Code
void brgc( int *a, int n, int idx, int reflect )
{
    if ( n == idx ) {
        printIntArr( a, n );
    } else {
        a[ idx ] = reflect;
        brgc( a, n, idx + 1, 0 );
        a[ idx ] = !reflect;
        brgc( a, n, idx + 1, 1 );
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        printf( "Usage...\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    int n = atoi( argv[ 1 ] );
    int *a = malloc( sizeof( int ) * n );
    brgc( a, n, 0, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/ package whatever; // don't place package name! /

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/ Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. /
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int numberofPeople=3;
        int size = 1<<numberofPeople;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            int num = i^(i>>1);
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
        }
    }
}
```